# 3D Touch cancels my custom gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have the following gesture recognizer to detect while a view is being touched. I use it to highlight hyperlinks in a label.

```
@implementation TouchGestureRecognizer

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled;
}

@end
```

I have a problem when the touch is a "deep" one as in the simulator or on an iPhone 6S if you press hard, with the iOS 9.0 SDK. A "shallow" press works as expected, but a "deep" press immediately cancels the gesture.

The release notes mention that the touchesMoved: is sent for force-touch gestures, but removing the `state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed` does not change the cancelling of that gesture.

Is there anything I can change on the above code to work on iPhone 6S (sim/device) while still on the iOS 9.0 SDK? Or is building with the iOS 9.1 SDK the only way to fix this?

Comment: I found that if I replace my custom gesture recognizer with a UILongPressGestureRecognizer, then it is not cancelled by deep presses. What is different there?